# SQL join(INNER JOIN )

Tags: sql, join

This part requires you to write **a simple inner join** of several tables. 
Write a SQL statement that returns a data set with all airports in London. The data set must contain, for each airport, the name of the city, the country, the airport code and its latitude and longi-tude

My answer here:

```
       SELECT  City.name, Country.name, Airport.code, Airport.latitude,
               Airport.longtitude 
       FROM City, Airport, Country
          WHERE Country.id = City.Country
          AND   Airport.city = City.id
          AND   City.name = "London"
```

Am I right? Do I need to write the keywords like "INNER JOIN" or "ON" on my code?

Comment: can u explain your table structure?

Comment: Sorry. Table  Airport have PRIMARY KEY (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES City (id)                              Table City have    PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (name, country),
   FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES Country (id)                           Table Country have PRIMARY KEY (id),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ok.

```
SELECT City.name, Country.name, Airport.code, Airport.latitude, Airport.longtitude 
FROM City, Airport, Country 
WHERE 
    Country.id = City.Country 
AND Airport.city = City.id 
AND City.name = "London"
```

But can also be write like this

```
SELECT City.name, Country.name, Airport.code, Airport.latitude, Airport.longtitude 
FROM 
    City 
    inner join Country ON Country.id = City.Country
    inner join Airport ON Airport.city = City.id 
WHERE 
    City.name = "London"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the question asks for a 'a simple inner join', then yes, you'll need to use those keywords! `INNER JOIN` is used to link tables that have matching columns. For example, if one table contains details about a city, another table can refer to it via its ID column, and a query using `INNER JOIN` can retrieve details from both. If the city details change, they only need to be changed in one table.

In your example, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    cty.name,
    ap.code,
    ap.latitude,
    ap.longtitude
FROM
    Airport ap
    INNER JOIN City c ON ap.city = c.id
    INNER JOIN Country cty ON c.Country = cty.id
WHERE
    c.name = "London"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       SELECT  City.name, Country.name, Airport.code, Airport.latitude,
               Airport.longtitude

       from Airport
            inner join city on Airport.city = City.id
            inner join Country ON Country.id = City.Country
       where 
            city.name='London'
```